# T-SQL STR() C#.NET LINQ to SQL Equivalent

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, t-sql, string

I'm trying to convert a standard SQL query to a LINQ to SQL query.

I was wondering what the LINQ equivalent of the T-SQL function [STR()](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/setu-sus_15.htm) is?

> STR (T-SQL)
>
> Returns character data converted from
>   numeric data.
>
> Syntax STR(float_expression[, length[,
>   decimal]])
>
> Arguments float_expression  Is an
>   expression of approximate numeric
>   (float) data type with a decimal
>   point. Do not use a function or
>   subquery as the float_expression in
>   the STR function.  length  Is the
>   total length, including decimal point,
>   sign, digits, and spaces. The default
>   is 10.  decimal  Is the number of
>   places to the right of the decimal
>   point.  Return Types char

I'm trying to explicitly set the number of decimal places for a field.

Please and thank you!

(I've tried Googling around, but Google keeps on translating str as "string" even with double quotes aroud str)

**EDIT**

I've tried .ToString("N2") which is exactly what I want, but LINQ isn't able to translate it.

**EDIT**

Clarification, I have a SQL field that is a double. I have to append/truncate to 2 decimal places. After that, I will append it with an additional string.  So therefore, I believe I do need to convert it to a string.  This is because I need to compare that generated string with another field that is of type varchar.  (I know this is idiotic because they should be the same type, etc, but I can't change the design of the database).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Huy,

There is a product (which I have no association with) that translates T-SQL queries into Linq queries. The name is Linqer (http://www.sqltolinq.com/). It's very inexpensive and has been a help to me in converting some of my more difficult queries.

Randy

Comment: Using Linqer, I typed in the following query:

Select Str(Id,2) from Master.Enterprise

Linqer created the following:

from t in db.Master_Enterprise
select new {
  Column1 = string.Format("{0:0}",t.ID)
}

Comment: string.Format works. Thank you!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f71z6k0c.aspx).

See the link for some examples of how to format it to your liking, or refer to the following:

- [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)
- [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

---

However, your statement here leads me to question whether you *really* want a string or not:

> I'm trying to explicitly set the number of decimal places for a field.

Perhaps you could clarify what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: I've tried .ToString("N2") which is exactly what I want, but LINQ isn't able to translate it.

Comment: Why don't you take the number as is from the database, then convert it to a string when you go to display it?

Comment: Hmmm after thinking about it, I should be able to do that.  Thanks for the help.